# Querying comma separated field?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to output a select dropdown options based on a comma separated field where if the user has been assigned an ID of 1 and 2 for example then I want to output the locations id has 1 and 2:

Users table:
id (which equals 1) and usergrouplocid which is a text field with (1,2)

[image]

Location Table:
id which auto_increment and a loc_id see iamge below:

[image]

My query is as follows:

```
$query = "SELECT room_location.*, client_room.*, users.* FROM room_location INNER JOIN client_room ON room_location.user_loc_id = client_room.id INNER JOIN users ON room_location.user_loc_id = users.userGroupLocID WHERE 1 IN (userGroupLocID) ORDER BY room_location.location";
```

The query above works fine but it only outputs where the id of 1 exists in usergrouplocid, so how do I get the query to find if 1, 2, 3 or 4 etc is in the usergrouplocid.

Comment: To be honest, I'd really suggest normalising your database tables to remove the CSV string column into a link table.

Comment: It is strongly recommended to redesign your database. You can use Many to Many relation. It can make a lot of mistake for you in the future.

Comment: Many thanks for comments, I will rethink this and redesign the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case you really need it sorted now without redesigning your database (which I would)...

```
$ids = array(1,2,4);

$query = "SELECT room_location.*, client_room.*, users.* FROM room_location INNER JOIN client_room ON room_location.user_loc_id = client_room.id INNER JOIN users ON room_location.user_loc_id = users.userGroupLocID WHERE userGroupLocID REGEXP '(^|,)(".implode('|',$ids).")(,|$)' ORDER BY room_location.location";
```

Comment: Yeah, but this will also match `12,42` etc.

Comment: @jensgram There, fixed