# Check if comma separated value exists in Database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I need to check if my comma separated value exists in Database. And my database also storing in comma separated.

My string is saved as "1,2,3,4,5" in database.

My search string is $bloggerscat = "2,5"

I have tried

```
(B.category_id LIKE ('%,$bloggerscat') OR B.category_id LIKE ('%$bloggerscat,%') OR B.category_id = '".$bloggerscat."')
```

Not getting proper result. Please help me.

Advanced thanks...

Comment: Prepare to receive a lot of people saying that storing comma separated values in database is very, very bad.

Comment: your query won't gives you 2,5 from the string you given in any way.. Your code will be like `(B.category_id LIKE ('%,2,5') OR B.category_id LIKE ('%2,5,%') OR B.category_id = '".2,5."')` 
nothing will match with your string

Comment: what if dataset is saved appears in form, `5,2`

Comment: Can we check through loop?

Comment: Possible already answered question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32372902/querying-comma-seperated-field

Comment: So i need to use like B.category_id REGEXP '(^|,)(".implode('|',$bloggerscat).")(,|$)' ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this,

```
$bloggerscat = '2,5'; // Your input here (string)

$set = explode(',',$bloggerscat); // get the numbers in $set array

$query = 'SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE '; // construct query

foreach ($set as $search)
{
    $query .= "FIND_IN_SET($search, column_name) OR "; // append every time for set 
}

$query = rtrim($query, ' OR'); // remove last OR

echo $query; // test
```

Will produce

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE FIND_IN_SET(2, column_name) OR FIND_IN_SET(5, column_name)
```

Will give you results from column `column_name` where comma separated sets have value either `2` or `5`.

Comment: Thanks Viral for solution.

Answer (score -1):

You have to store the string as ",1,2,3,4,5," in database
then try this code

```
$currStr        =   "2,5";
$explCurrStr    =   explode(",",$currStr);
foreach($explCurrStr as $key=>$all){
    if($key==0){
        $sql.=" B.category_id LIKE ('%,".$all.",')  ";
    }else{
        $sql.=" OR B.category_id LIKE ('%,".$all.",')  ";
    }
}
```